# js: How navigate to new url and get callBack when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a JS function that navigates to an 3rd party url and call a function once this page is loaded;

```
document.location = "http://ww.example.com";
window.onload = function () { alert('example.com page loaded!") }
```

Can this be done ?

Comment: [**Same-origin policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: You mean: it cannot be done ?

Comment: what exactly is your use case, there must some other approach to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The execution environment for the first page will be destroyed before the one for the new page is created. They cannot interact.

The closest you could come would be to pass some data (through the URL / a cookie / local storage) that the other page would look for in a script that always runs on it.

Comment: well, it is not my page, it is a 3rd party website

Comment: Then it is completely impossible. Anything else would be an XSS security hole built into the browser.

Comment: Since you want to deal with a third party site (and assuming you don't have their co-operation): You can't. If you could it would be a massive security problem.